# Is there a way programmatically change the virtual memory threshold of a process?

Tags: c#, windows-xp, monitoring

I am currently writing a WatchDog application to monitor the memory usage of a few services. The services are running on a Windows XP. From what I have researched, the default virtual memory threshold for a process is about 1.8GB. Is there a way to modify the threshold programatically?

Comment: A 32 bit process gets 2GB address space by default, and 3GB if large address aware is enabled (both in the OS and in the executable image). Changing the OS setting is high impact, and shouldn't be done by normal applications.

Comment: If you need lots of memory, use 64 bit applications on a 64 bit OS. Buying a new computer+64 bit OS is probably cheaper than working around the memory limit.